# PyUSB , Como manipular los datos

Tags: python, usb

Hola tengo un problema con la librería PyUSB y a no encuentro la respuesta por ningún lado,
básicamente una vez conectado el dispositivo USB y haberlo leído ,¿como puedo manipular los datos?, por ejemplo extraer el contenido del mismo, no encuentro nada acerca de eso en la librería oficial de [PyUSB](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst).

Mi código esta aquí y no me da error de **Backend** ya que descargue `libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0` para usar `.info` y tampoco me da ningún error, simplemente no muestra el nombre del dispositivo ni nada con lo que poder trabajar.

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
import usb.backend.libusb1
import usb.control

dev = usb.core.find(find_all=True)


if dev is None:
    raise ValueError('Our device is not connected')
```

Esto me decuelve esto:

```
C:\Users\Lenovo>C:/Users/Lenovo/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Modulos Python/Practicas python/Practicas.py"
```

EDITADO: si desconecto el USB tampoco me devuelve ningún fallo, así que nunca se estableció conexión

**Solo están las lineas de código que busca el USB**

Answer (score 2):

El código funciona, es sólo que nunca usas el resultado.

Ejecute tu programa agregando estas líneas al final:

```
for d in dev:
    print(d)
```

La variable `d` es del tipo `usb.core.Device`.

Produjo un largo listado como el que sigue:

```
DEVICE ID 8087:8000 on Bus 002 Address 002 =================
 bLength                :   0x12 (18 bytes)
 bDescriptorType        :    0x1 Device
 bcdUSB                 :  0x200 USB 2.0
 bDeviceClass           :    0x9 Hub
 bDeviceSubClass        :    0x0
 bDeviceProtocol        :    0x1
 bMaxPacketSize0        :   0x40 (64 bytes)
 idVendor               : 0x8087
 idProduct              : 0x8000
 bcdDevice              :    0x5 Device 0.05
 iManufacturer          :    0x0 
 iProduct               :    0x0 
 iSerialNumber          :    0x0 
 bNumConfigurations     :    0x1
  CONFIGURATION 1: 0 mA ====================================
   bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)
   bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration
   wTotalLength         :   0x19 (25 bytes)
   bNumInterfaces       :    0x1
   bConfigurationValue  :    0x1
   iConfiguration       :    0x0 
   bmAttributes         :   0xe0 Self Powered, Remote Wakeup
   bMaxPower            :    0x0 (0 mA)
    INTERFACE 0: Hub =======================================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x1
     bInterfaceClass    :    0x9 Hub
     bInterfaceSubClass :    0x0
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
     iInterface         :    0x0 
      ENDPOINT 0x81: Interrupt IN ==========================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x3 Interrupt
       wMaxPacketSize   :    0x1 (1 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0xc
```